# jenkins job fails with yaml has no attribute full loader

Tags: docker, jenkins, pyyaml

i have upgraded the Pyyaml version to 5.3.1.
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import yaml
> > > yaml.**version**
> > > '5.3.1'

When i run it locally on the server it works fine but when a docker based job does the same thing it fails with following error:

20:45:05 ############ Run docker container ############
20:45:05  Network seastone-02_default  Creating
20:45:06  Network seastone-02_default  Created
20:45:06  Container seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  Creating
20:45:06  Container seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  Created
20:45:06 Attaching to seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |   File "CRobot.py", line 258, in 
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |     main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7], sys.argv[8])
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |   File "CRobot.py", line 87, in main
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |     testTag = getTagFromConfigFile()
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |   File "CRobot.py", line 76, in getTagFromConfigFile
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |     caseInfo = YamlParse.getTestCaseInfo()
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |   File "/crobot/crobot/YamlParse.py", line 57, in getTestCaseInfo
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |     return parse('../config/TestCases.yaml')
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |   File "/crobot/crobot/YamlParse.py", line 22, in parse
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  |     dict = yaml.load(str, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1  | AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'
20:45:06 seastone-02-seastone_seastone-e02-1 exited with code 1

Do we have to update something on the jenkins?

cmdline used:  ./start_crobot.sh -s seastone_diag -p seastone_seastone-e02 -t CONFIG_FILE 1 -e NO_EXIT  (ignore its an internal gig to run certain scripts)

i tried upgrading the pyyaml version but it didnt help

Comment: What is the command you are using to get that error?

Comment: i shared a python command line.
cmdline used: ./start_crobot.sh -s seastone_diag -p seastone_seastone-e02 -t CONFIG_FILE

This runs fine on my  server 10.x.x.x. but i run it via jenkins as a job i get that error

Comment: Issue resolved. Thanks .
The jenkins file was updated on the server to include :
pip3 install pyyaml == 5.3